# dgrid dnd implement onDrop event

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid, dojo-dnd

I would like to implement a custom behavior of the drop event of DnD in dgrid. I have the following gdrig declaration:

```
this.grid = new (declare([OnDemandGrid, Editor, DnD, DijitRegistry]))({
                        region: "center",
                        collection: this.store,
                        selectionMode: 'single',
                        columns: ...
                    }, this.gridNode);

                    this.grid.startup();
```

What I exactly want is simple: after I drag and drop a row in the grid (reorder the items in dgrid) I want to trigger an event (function - say to get the current row and manipulate it, etc.).
The problem is that I do not know how to override the onDrop event or drag event. Can someone give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy mechanism to replace onDrop, however it is not at all obvious how to keep but extend the existing onDrop functionality.  This is because onDrop lives in a class called [DnDSource](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.7/dojo/dnd/Source) which the grid creates.  Fortunately this is a [dependency that can be injected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection) (via a property called dndConstructor).  Here's my solution:

```
var MyDnDSource = declare([DnDSource], {
    onDrop: function() {
        this.inherited(arguments); // This is the original onDrop functionality
        console.log('This is my additional onDrop functionality');        
  }
});

this.grid = new (declare([OnDemandGrid, Editor, DnD, DijitRegistry]))({
                    dndConstructor: MyDnDSource,
                    region: "center",
                    collection: this.store,
                    selectionMode: 'single',
                    columns: ...
                }, this.gridNode);

this.grid.startup();
```